# Formula For Contains Value or Value Before Hyphen?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am writing a formula to check if a field1 contains value from field2 or its value before the first hyphen.

```
Field1    Field2     
ABCDE     ABC    
ABCDE     ABC-XY
```

I tried:

```
IF(CONTAINS(Field1__c, Field2__c),True,False)
```

In First Scenario answer is correct but second scenario is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic will be like this, though I have not compiled.

```
CONTAINS(Field1__c, Field2__c) || 
IF(FIND("-", Field2__c),
CONTAINS(Field1__c,LEFT(Field2__c,FIND("-", Field2__c))),false)
```

Comment: I think you need to check for hyphen first, sounds like OP doesn't want to check that initial condition if the second field contains a hyphen.

Comment: I have assumed that either of the 1st or 2nd condition should satisfies to find the value